# ClassNotFoundException in SecurityExtension.php line 20

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a quite mature project and I decided to move it to a different development environment. After setting everything up, I am now getting this exception:

```
ClassNotFoundException in SecurityExtension.php line 20:
Attempted to load class "Twig_Function_Method" from the global namespace.
Did you forget a "use" statement?
```

Where is this coming from? I am not even sure where to start. 
By the stack trace, seems like it is something to do with `assetic`.

However, when I execute console command, for example `cache:clear`.
I am getting this:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException]
  Attempted to load class "Twig_Function_Method" from the global namespace.
  Did you forget a "use" statement?
```

Similar, but now I am not even getting any more details than that.

Comment: what symfony version you use?

Comment: Symfony version 2.7.35. I am starting some prep work to move to 3, but that will take a while.

Comment: Twig_function_method went away a few twig versions ago.  I'm guessing you tried to upgrade parts of your project by manually editing composer.json.  There is a fair amount of information on this out there.  Perhaps the most straight forward approach is to start a new 2.7 project and then add bundles one by one to get the correct versions.